# How to get the average of a row in a 2D list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and I'm working with a 2D list and not exactly sure how to get the average of the rows.

For example I have this list:

```
myList = [[70, 80, 90], [30, 40, 50]]
```

and I would like to get the average of the first and second row.

Something like this:

(70 + 80 + 90)/3 = 80

(30 + 40 + 50)/3 = 40

I'm implementing my `print_student_average` function, but I'm a little lost. Someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please.

Here's my code:

```
def main():
    myList = [[70, 80, 90], [30, 40, 50]]

    print(print_student_average(myList))
    print_exam_average(myList)

def print_student_average(myList):

    total_sum = [sum(i) for i in range(len(myList))]
    average = total_sum/3

    return average

def print_exam_average(myList):

    col_totals = [ sum(x)/2 for x in zip(*myList) ]

    for col in col_totals:
        print("the average of the exam is: ", col)


main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do what you want. Hope it helps!

```
def main():
    myList = [[70, 80, 90], [30, 40, 50]]

    print(print_student_average(myList))
    print_exam_average(myList)

def print_student_average(myList):

    return [sum(row)/len(row) for row in myList]

def print_exam_average(myList):

    col_totals = [ sum(x)/len(myList) for x in zip(*myList) ]

for col in col_totals:
    print("the average of the exam is: ", col)


main()
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want, you can use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org) package and its function [`mean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html).

To compute the average mark of each student, given `myList`, the code would look like:

```
import numpy

def print_student_average(myList):
    students_avg = numpy.mean(myList, axis=1)
    for avg in students_avg:
        print(avg)
    return students_avg
```

Note that `axis=1` determines that the average is calculate over the rows.
With the list in the example provided, the output is:

```
80.0
40.0
```

Similarly, you can get the average for every exam using the same numpy function:

```
def print_exams_average(myList):
    exams_avg = numpy.mean(myList, axis=0)
    for avg in exams_avg:
        print(avg)
    return exams_avg
```

In this case `axis=0` to get the average over columns, and the result for the list provided in the example is:

```
50.0
60.0
70.0
```

About the problem in your `print_student_average`,

```
 total_sum = [sum(i) for i in range(len(myList))]
```

is the main problem. [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) returns a list of integers starting from 0 to the length of the list, which in the example is 2. With the `for` statement you iterate over each value of the list from `range`, and then you are trying to use `sum` over an integer, which does not work as it is not a list. The solution that follows more closely your code is already provided in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about this logic

```
mylist = [[70,80,90],[30,40,50]]
avglist = []
for x in mylist:
    temp = 0
    counter = 0
    for y in x:     
        temp = temp + y
        counter = counter + 1
    avglist.append(temp/counter)
print(avglist)
```

Answer (score 0):

list comprehension

```
[sum(r)/len(r) for r in myList]
```

just for print

```
[print((sum(r)/len(r)) for r in myList]
```

Comment: Never use a list comprehension just tor the side effects. Just use a normal for loop instead of creating a list of `None` values and then discarding it again.

Comment: Also: the parentheses are not balanced.